# Laravel framework isn't starting up, why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, laravel

I've done as said in the tutorial http://laravel.com/docs/quick installed everything and yet when I start up apache I get this:

[image]

Why is it so and what can I do to fix this?

Note: there is a base route that goes to `/` and for some reason it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried going into public directory? That should be your public path.

Comment: @Xeen: if you change your vhost `DocumentRoot` to that folder, it will work from the root of your domain as you expect.